# How to install apps on the second external SD card?

Tags: applications, storage, app2sd

I have an Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) tablet. It has two external memory cards. All apps are installed on external memory card 1, but not on external memory 2, even though I have lots of space on external memory card 2. How can I change that?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Installing to SDCard by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43517/16575).