# Moving sdcard to ExtSdCard

Tags: external-sd, storage, internal-sd, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I was an Android beginner, I know nothing of 'hacking' some Android stuff. I found several issues of this case but no one that I look pretty ideal for my case.

My Samsung Galaxy  Ace 2 has been inserted a new SD Card after a several time using no SD Card. That makes the system create `sdcard` in it's internal storage. Then my storage information (`Setting -> Storage`) become 3 parts, which: **Device memory** (internal), **USB Storage** (internal), and **SD Card** (extSdCard). This thing become very annoying since my internal wasn't so big.

And when I open my **Gallery** it pop some notice `There is not enough space (0 MB) in your device memory. Delete some files.` And always redirect me to the **Files**. On my **Files** there is 2 folders, which: **extSdCard** and **sdcard0**. On the setting of Files. I **can't** change the `Set home directory` that refers to `/storage/sdcard0` to (my hope) `/storage/extSdCard`.

I done trying to moving all apps to internal storage with hoping that **USB Storage** not full, but it doesn't give any good solution just yet. I read several post and forum, also several solution using `adb` but I don't think those solution can manage all problem, since because of this case, I can't save any voice note or picture from social chatting apps, in some case, I can't receive any bluetooth transfer also.

So I want that **USB Storage** begone, and my `sdcard0` was symlinked to the real external SD Card, or another step that make my system become like the old like Android system. Please help me. Thanks a lot before.

FYI: right now, my phone isn't rooted yet. But I can root it anytime, if it really needed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works on the *Ace 2*, but you might wish to take a look at [External 2 Internal SD](http://www.appbrain.com/app/External-2-Internal-SD/eu.codlab.int2ext). Was originally written for the S3, but should work for other devices as well. Please report back whether it helped.

Comment: @izzy: I don't really know about the system of Android 4.4. But how if I just re-install the whole system of the Android while SD Card was inserted. Do you think that way can work? I mean, the `ExtSdCard` can be directly known as the `sd_card0`.

Comment: I don't have 4.4 on any of my devices (and I don't want to). But I'm afraid that would again install anything on internal ("primary storage"). Maybe this is helpful: [Installing to SDCard by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43517/16575)? If your device is rooted, you might also wish to check our [link2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I meant 4.2 :P. Ok I'll try to looking on it also. I had tried your first solution but still not doing fine and there's some step I should notice more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for upvoting this question but I'm afraid I still have no answer until this day either majority people. But let me share my latest research about this case which actually would be lame because I post this question pretty much long time ago. So, here it is.

When I do my research about it on the device, I try to **root** it, try to **swapping** the the storage and whatsoever (*please notice that my Android's knowledge was not too much, so I think I may not trying all methods*). It's all result nothing but pain and brick phone in the end of the day.

So I bring my phone to Service Center and after they re-install it I asked them about that case/issue, they trying to answer with '*not-clear-answer-to-preserve-reputation*' answer, until I force them to spit the truth. Then finally they says that how **Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 works**. So, that's is, my last conclusion that this phone was made for experiment or whatsoever. I face this kind of experiment issue form Samsung not just once

*So, I hope this story can brought us some unclear light to overcome the unclear darkness that coming from this phone* (you can skip this last unclear sentence :p). Peace out :D