# Internal SD card as default storage

Tags: storage

I want to install apps on internal sd card but instead all apps get installed on phone storage which is low in memory

Comment: Depending on your Android version this storage is shared and installing apps on SD card or moving them there doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Yupp. But we already have a couple of questions on this which are answered, e.g. [Installing to SDCard by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43517/16575).

Answer (score 0):

You need root. If you have root, you can use [Link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) app, which switch internal and external storage.