# I can't use the sd card to download apps

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, insufficient-memory

I just got a new phone but when I try to download something it says insufficient space but my sd card has plenty. How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing to SDCard by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43517/installing-to-sdcard-by-default)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please start checking our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains some first aid and links to more. Then come back here and let us know how you solved your issue – or tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: That's because your internal memory is full ,allmost. To place app's on SD card you will need apps2sd or link2sd app and phone has to be rooted, also if you have android version 6.0+ you can use feature called adoptable storage so sd card will behave like internal, noo root required but you wouldn't be able to use sd with other phone only if you format it first

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card can be as big as possible, but Android won't use it. It's not safe for Android to assume your external SD card is always accessible.
Depending on your Android version, your internal storage is shared with your device storage i.e: Applications will not use less storage even if you move them to your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following;

1. Clear cache or app data.
2. Uninstall unused app.
3. Root your device and use link2sd
4. If your device used MTK processor, try to repartition your internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

When you find some app on google-play-store and install it, the apk is downloaded to /data/local, i.e. to your internal-storage. You can't change that. Its after this your settings come into picture, your if have set to install it on sdcard it installs to sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

I did this steps in my Zenfone 5, so I'm pretty sure it'll work. (WARNING : You will void your warranty!)

1. Root your device. Then I suggest to take a full backup with Titanium Backup.
2. Repartition your SD card, add 1 ext3 or ext4 partition. You can use TWRP or CWM. (WARNING : It will destroy your SDcard contents! Make a backup first!)
3. Install Link2SD from Play Store. Select your second partition type, based on what you choose at step 2.
4. Open settings, look for auto link, enable. (Can't remember the exact name ...)
5. If you want, you can link already installed apps to your sdcard.

After this, when you installed new application, it will be symlinked to your sdcard's second partition. 
Enjoy extra space.

Or better, remove all bloatware with titanium backup. Or use unbloated custom rom.

Your choice. Your warranty has been voided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer version of android, you can format the SD card to act as internal storage. This essentially acts as additional internal storage and can be extended to whatever your phone is capable of supporting. This should solve your storage issue.

If you have a phone with an android version not compatible with this, you may be able to move some apps that are taking a lot of space, however they will open a lot slower once they're on your external memory.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to lack of space in your device. If you transfer data in your phone (Apps, Images, Music files, etc.) into the SD card space will be free on your device and then you can install more apps.
In the following way you can transfer applications into your SD card.

> Settings → Apps → On SD Card → Select the app → Move to SD Card

In this way you can transfer the installed apps in your phone to the SD card. Then you'll be able to install apps. Do the same thing for newly installed apps too to make sure you have enough space in your phone at anytime.

Note that "If you remove the SD card then the apps transferred into the SD card will not work"

Answer (score 0):

From the settings you will have to go to storage settings and then you will have to enable the sd card storage which would probably allow you to install all the apps and other downloads easily on sd card nd I would also prefer to buy an card with larger space in it.

Answer (score -3):

You may put your SD card to another phone. If it doesn't work either,then it means that your SD card may be crashed. In this way, you have to format the SD card and replug it to check it out. Make sure you have tick " Save new apps to SD card"option on your phone. Hope this can help you.

Comment: *"insufficient space"* message is caused by altogether different things. See the tag wiki of [tag:insufficient-memory.]