# I formatted my SD card as internal storage, downloads still go to the phones internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, downloading

Yo, I just formatted my SD card as internal storage, and the storage section says that in my device storage I have 30 GB, but downloads still go to the phones internal storage, is this how its supposed to be?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43522

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)