# Formatted my sd card as internal storage in my Xiamoi phone. but still getting no enough space message when installing apps

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, insufficient-memory, xiaomi, adoptable-storage

I have a Xiamoi note 8 phone running android 9. It has 32gb internal storage and I used most of it, so I decided to buy an sd card to use as internal storage.
I went in settings chose the format as internal storage option. It then asked me to move data to the new internal storage, I clicked yes then after it finished I restarted my phone and It still was giving the low on storage message.

when I open the file manager it shows the phone's data split evenly between the sd card and the storage.

when I open the settings and go to storage it only shows the phone's original 32gb.
I searched a lot but couldn't find a solid solution for this problem.

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43522