# Getting rid of my SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

Very frustrated so please forgive the rant.

I've given up searching Google because despite well written search queries such as

"How do I move everything from my SD card to my phone"

or

"How do I get rid of my SD card"

I get results that all have to do with moving stuff TO my SD card FROM my phone.

My SD card is flaking out on me and I have gone through several attempts to scan it and fix it and it never stays good for long.

My phone has plenty of internal storage I just want to completely get rid of my SD card but I don't want to lose the stuff I have on my SD card or break where things look to find stuff like pictures and music.

Does anyone know of ANY forums or tutorials to do the opposite of what it seems everyone else wants to do in relation to SD card storage.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Doesn't cover data, but you can set your default app install location to internal storage using this question: [How do I stop apps from installing themselves to my SD-card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/)

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed any Apps on the SDCard, you can simply move them back to internal storage via the *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps* menu, walking your downloaded apps one by one and see whether it is installed on SDCard. This should be your first step.

For the remaining files: If your device offers an "internal SDCard", you could simply use a file manager like e.g. [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to move "normal files" from the external to the internal SDCard.

Both steps done, remove the SDCard (either should down your device to do so, or simply use the *Settings→Storage* menu to unmount the card first if you can access it without shutting down the device).

Optional step: Once the card is removed, you could check again if you still can move apps to SDCard, as the device might use the *internal* SDCard for this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the phone, you may not be able to move files from the SD card to the phone's internal storage.  What you *can* do, however, is buy a replacement SD card and move all the files from the old card to the new one.

If your computer has a card reader (many laptops do), you can use that to copy the files from the old card to your hard drive.  Or you can connect your phone to your computer with a USB cable and access the files that way.  Then remove the old card and insert the new one, and copy the files back.

Comment: Other than pictures and music, if the user had installed many apps (which might have been moved to SD card) then, it would make sense to use Titanium Backup to back up the apps and its data.

Comment: I've got a Galaxy S2

My Husband has an S3 and he runs his phone without an SD card at all. I was hoping I could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any experience with Linux, you could connect your SD card to your PC using a card reader, and use the `dd` command to make a direct dump of the card's contents. Then you could use `dd` again to write the contents onto a new card of the same capacity.

(it sounds like your card may be on the verge of total failure, so you should do this as soon as possible, if you have important photos/music on it!)