# How to root Android 4.1 in order to use SD card for internal storage?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage

I made the mistake of buying a cheap Chinese phone on Ebay to use on Three or Orange in the UK, a **4" Malata I60 Android 4.1 Dual Core MT6577 1GHz**. It's okay for what little I need, except the internal storage shows as a total of 179MB.

I've moved whatever apps I can to my 30GB SD card and using App Cache Cleaner, but I am still only left with 36.8MB of free space.

This is causing warnings whenever updates are found and even causing updates to fail for lack of space if I am actively using the phone.

Does anyone know where I could find reliable step-by-step guides to rooting Android 4.1 and using the SD card for internal storage?

Comment: [How To Install Apps on SD Card For Androids](http://techtter.blogspot.nl/2012/05/how-to-install-apps-on-sd-card-for.html?utm_source=BP_recent)
Try this no need to root.

Comment: It looks like that website's just a copy of these answers, with a bit of how to install ADB at the start, http://android.stackexchange.com/a/4976/156 and http://android.stackexchange.com/a/4978/156